# Trouble with PHP pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Followed this guide on how to paginate results from MySQL with PHP:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

Ended up with this for the paginator class file:

```
<?php

class Paginator {

     private $_conn;
        private $_limit;
        private $_page;
        private $_query;
        private $_total;

public function __construct( $conn, $query ) {

    $this->_conn = $conn;
    $this->_query = $query;

    $rs= $this->_conn->query( $this->_query );
    $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

}

public function getData( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

    $this->_limit   = $limit;
    $this->_page    = $page;

    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        $query      = $this->_query;
    } else {
        $query      = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) * $this->_limit ) . ", $this->_limit";
    }
    $rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );

    while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $results[]  = $row;
    }

    $result         = new stdClass();
    $result->page   = $this->_page;
    $result->limit  = $this->_limit;
    $result->total  = $this->_total;
    $result->data   = $results;

    return $result;
}

public function createLinks( $links, $list_class ) {
    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        return '';
    }

    $last       = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

    $start      = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links : 1;
    $end        = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page + $links : $last;

    $html       = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

    $class      = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

    if ( $start > 1 ) {
        $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=1">1</a></li>';
        $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
    }

    for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
        $class  = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
        $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }

    if ( $end < $last ) {
        $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
        $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
    }

    $class      = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

    $html       .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
  }
}
?>
```

It is paginating the results, but I am ending up with 1 result on page 1, 2 results on page 2, 3 results on page 3... etc.

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here?

My index.php file:

```
<?php
  require_once 'Paginator.class.php';

  $conn       = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'uname', 'password', 'dbname' );

  $limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 25;
  $page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
  $links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;
  $query      = "SELECT Host, CVE, Name, Risk, CVSS FROM Vulnerabilities";

  $Paginator  = new Paginator( $conn, $query );

  $results    = $Paginator->getData( $page, $limit );
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Vulnerability Pagination</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>Vulnerability Pagination</h1>
                    <?php echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' ); ?>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-rounded">
                        <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th width="15%">Host</th>
                                <th width="15%">CVE</th>
                                <th width="50%">Name</th>
                                <th width="10%">Risk</th>
                                <th width="10%">CVSS</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
                              <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['Host']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['CVE']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['Name']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['Risk']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['CVSS']; ?></td>
                              </tr>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                  <?php echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' ); ?>
                </div>  
        </div> 
        </body>
</html>
```

To me it seems like it is iterating the page number and the number of results per page, but I can't decide why.. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There's some irony here that you're creating a site about vulnerabilities that's full of vulnerabilities. This query builder is a gigantic liability.

Comment: I imagine that you are correct, but for now am I trying to get something made that works, and after that look into making it secure.

But to be forward with you, this is not a public facing site, and is not a product or service that I am going to be offering.

It is so that I can keep track of remediation progress on my own network because I can't afford an upgraded license for Nessus that does all of this.

Any ideas are appreciated along with your criticism or reference to a better resource than the one I used for this pagination method.

Comment: Do it properly the first time and it will always be secure. Slap it together and cut corners on things like this and you'll have no idea how vulnerable it is. Making insecure code secure is really tricky, very taxing, and often a lot more complicated than you think, especially if you've doubled or tripled down on a design pattern that doesn't lend itself to using placeholder values. Using best practices out of the gate avoids all of this and isn't even hard. It saves time almost immediately by side-stepping escaping problems.

Comment: One way or the other, doing it securely or not doesn't sound like it will change the problem I am having with this method of pagination.

I will read about best practices in the meantime, but don't understand how the way I am doing this affects your ability to answer the question I was asking.

Do you know what is going on with the issue I am having?

I appreciate your advice, though.

Comment: The problem is this Paginator is implemented in such a way that prevents you from doing things securely, so even if you do get it working it's going to have to be removed in the future and done properly, easily tripling the amount of work you have to do here. Why not use an ORM like Eloquent which [already supports pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)? This is a solved problem.

Comment: Because when it comes to php, I am a scrub.

I am not really sure even where to start, since if I was the one using this, I can just do everything I need to in SQL.

But since I can't, I am trying to learn PHP enough to get this going.

So I need to use an ORM, and Laravel is a good place to start?

Is there anything else I should know or some links to best practices?

It is worth noting that typically I take open source projects that are already working and mold to my needs.. but in this case, I couldn't find one and am building from scratch.

So, I do appreciate the input

Comment: An ORM is a good place to start because it will both protect you from having to do SQL for every single little thing, which carries a huge risk of doing it badly, and yet it still allows you to get your hands dirty when you need to. Most show you the SQL they generate in a log so you can always check what they're doing and make adjustments as necessary, and it'll probably show you some tricks to composing SQL queries you're not aware of, like how to use `JOIN` or `IN(...)` effectively.

Comment: You should only build your own from scratch if you've already used a half dozen of these things already and know them inside and out, plus you have a *lot* of time to dedicate to design, implementation, testing, and documentation of whatever you're building. These are core components and they need to be the absolute highest quality possible. Half-assing your database layer means everything built on top of it is going to have unpredictable problems and you'll always be second-guessing your self, wondering if it's an issue with your hand-rolled ORM.

Comment: Laravel isn't the only solution, there's many frameworks out there, but it's a good place to start. If you think it's overly complicated there's more minimal versions of same, but what these all have in common is they're already implemented, already tested, and they have a community contributing new features, bug fixes, and add-ons for them. You won't have to write every single line of code yourself, find and fix every bug, and so on.

Comment: Ok, I will start looking into that.

I appreciate the guidance. Thank you